# How to check if the provider value is changed or not in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I want to check if the provider value is changed or not because I am calling the api in the init state and want to update the data according to filter using provider.
And I'm following MVVM can anyone suggest me how can I achieve this.
This is my provider class

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class FilterProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<String> _filterItems = [
    "usd",
    "top100",
    "1hr",
  ];
  List<String> get filterItems => _filterItems;
  void setPrice(String price) {
    _filterItems[0] = price;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void setCTS(String noOfCoins) {
    _filterItems[1] = noOfCoins;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void setPriceChange(String change) {
    _filterItems[2] = change;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

And this is my view can anyone have an idea how can I achieve this.

```
class CoinsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const CoinsPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<CoinsPage> createState() => _CoinsPageState();
}

class _CoinsPageState extends State<CoinsPage> {
  late CoinsViewModel viewModel = CoinsViewModel();
  List<CoinDetailsModel>? item;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    viewModel.loadCoinData("marketCap", "desc");
    viewModel.scrollController.addListener(viewModel.pagination);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double columnWidth = screenWidth / 5;
    double mar = (columnWidth / 5) + 1;
    // var margin = EdgeInsets.all(mar);
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<CoinsViewModel>(
        create: (BuildContext context) => viewModel,
        child: Consumer2<CoinsViewModel, FilterProvider>(
          builder: (context, viewModel, filterProvider, _) {
            debugPrint("length ${viewModel.coinsModel.length}");
            item = viewModel.coinsModel;
            //TODO Filter
            var usd = context.watch<FilterProvider>().filterItems[0];

            debugPrint("Filter $usd");
            return Scaffold(
              
            );
          },
        ));
  }

  
}
```

I have tried this

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<MyProvider>(
      builder: (context, myProvider, child) {
        if (myProvider.myValue == someValue) {
          // do something if the value has not changed
        } else {
          // do something if the value has changed
        }
        return Text(myProvider.myValue.toString());
      },
    );
  }
}
```

But if I want to go back to the first item it won't update

Answer (score 0):

Yes I got the way of doing it correctly check the code just wrap viemodel with provider

```
class CoinsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const CoinsPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<CoinsPage> createState() => _CoinsPageState();
}

class _CoinsPageState extends State<CoinsPage> {
  late CoinsViewModel viewModel = CoinsViewModel();
  List<CoinDetailsModel>? item;

 

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  

    // var margin = EdgeInsets.all(mar);
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<ViewModel>(
      create: (BuildContext context) => viewModel,
      child: Consumer<Provider>(
        builder: (ctx, filterItems, _) {
         
          return Consumer<ViewModel>(builder: (context, viewModel, _) {
            
            );
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }

}
```